# How to record sound in OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, voice

I need to record voice from built-in microphone using only Terminal.app in Mac OS X. Is there any way?

Comment: You can run applescripts from the command line.  That should do it for you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Install brew and then install sox

```
$ brew install sox

$ sox -d recording.wav
```

Comment: How do you record audio out only, not the microphone

Comment: does this interfere with skype or any other recording apps?

Comment: /tmp bemmu$ sox -d recording.wav
dyld: Symbol not found: _lame_close
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.1_1/lib/libsox.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.1_1/lib/libsox.2.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Did not work for me, no sound there. though volume input is set to 96. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: `sox` can record to ogg?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Yes seems like it, check `man soxformat`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich If you're using Homebrew, you will need to install sox with `brew install sox --with-libvorbis` to record with ogg. (If sox is already installed, you will need to `brew remove sox` first.) Then you can do `sox -d recording.ogg`.

Comment: how to end the recording? At the moment I'm using your instruction of `sox -d recording.wav`, but am having to end using `ctrl + c`, the resulting file has no sound, although it has size (it's not an empty file). I don't know if this is a result of me using `ctrl+c` or what.

Answer (score 3):

As [epatel mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758438/68338), but using the port system instead:

```
$ sudo port install sox
```

Comment: That should be a comment on his question, not a new answer.